# Are you permitted to listen to Christian music which forms songs directly from the text of the Psalms?

Tags: music, christianity

There is a band called [Sons of Korah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sons_of_Korah) who make music with lyrics taken directly from the English text of Psalms, without any additional lines. 
(They obviously took their band name from the Biblical Sons of Korach, who wrote a selection of psalms in Sefer Tehillim.)

Is one permitted to listen to such a band or would it still count as music made to praise their god?

Here is an example of one of their songs: [Psalm 91](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUZhTMZF_1I)

---

Note: I don't know what to put into the title. :)

Comment: @DanF - The music just happens to be composed by Christians. It is not used in churches; at least, that's not what it was intended for. I'm sure there are those who sing them in church though. I guess my doubts were coming from the fact that it's not just Christian composers, but they are taking quotations from the Bible and might be taken by some as them praising their god, ie, Jesus.

Comment: I strongly disagree that this is a duplicate. Consider especially the tshuva from Reb Moshe accepted as the answer there. Although that answer doesn't quote it, Reb Moshe differentiates when the instrument is not specifically for A.Z. I should hope Tehillim is at least as much not designated for A.Z.

Comment: As much as the answer there didn't explain the issues, that tshuva was not discussing when the A.Z. song was taken from us.